# How to inject Input() in unit testing?

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine

So i try to do some unit testing on a component. But I have some problems with Input() parameter. And then especially a component in the component

SO I have this component:

```
export class EcheqDisplayComponent implements OnInit {
  echeq: EcheqSubmissionApi;


  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.echeq = this.route.snapshot.data['submission'];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getAnswers(page: EcheqPageApi): any[] {
    return page.elements.map(element => this.echeq.answers[element.name]);
  }
}
```

and the template:

```
<div class="echeq-display" *ngIf="echeq">
  <header class="echeq-display-header header">
    <div class="echeq-display-info">
      <h1 class="heading echeq-display-heading">
        {{ echeq.definition.title }}
      </h1>
      <div class="sub-heading echeq-display-subheading">
        <span class="echeq-display-creator">
          Toegekend door:
          {{ echeq.assignedByProfName ? echeq.assignedByProfName : 'Het Systeem' }}
        </span>
        <span class="echeq-display-date">{{
          echeq.definition.createdOnUtc | date: 'dd MMM'
        }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <app-meta-box
      [metadata]="{
        numPages: echeq.definition.numPages,
        vPoints: echeq.definition.awardedVPoints
      }"
    ></app-meta-box>
  </header>
  <main class="echeq-display-questions body">
    <app-echeq-question
      *ngFor="let page of echeq.definition.pages; let i = index"
      [page]="page"
      [readonly]="true"
      [number]="i + 1"
      [answers]="getAnswers(page)"
    ></app-echeq-question>
  </main>
</div>
```

and the unit test:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { EcheqDisplayComponent } from './echeq-display.component';
import { ParticipantEcheqModule } from '../../participant-echeq.module';
import { RouterModule, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { MockActivatedRoute } from 'src/app/shared/mocks/MockActivatedRoute';
import { MetaData } from '../meta-box/meta-box.component';

describe('EcheqDisplayComponent', () => {
  let component: EcheqDisplayComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EcheqDisplayComponent>;
  const metaData: MetaData = new MetaData();
  // const metaDataInfo = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;


  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: MockActivatedRoute }
      ],
      imports:[
        ParticipantEcheqModule

      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EcheqDisplayComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  fit('should create component', () => {
    metaData.numPages = 20;
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

But it stay saying:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'numPages' of undefined.

So what I have to change that it is working?

Thank you

So the MetaData is from the app-meta-box component.it looks like this:

```
export class MetaData {
  numPages: number;
  vPoints: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-meta-box',
  templateUrl: './meta-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./meta-box.component.scss']
})
export class MetaBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() metadata: MetaData;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

This is the mock class:

```
export class MockActivatedRoute {
  public snapshot = {
      data: {
         submission: {
           answers: {}
         }
      }
  };
}
```

I have it now like this:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { EcheqDisplayComponent } from './echeq-display.component';
import { ParticipantEcheqModule } from '../../participant-echeq.module';
import { RouterModule, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { MockActivatedRoute } from 'src/app/shared/mocks/MockActivatedRoute';
import { MetaData } from '../meta-box/meta-box.component';

describe('EcheqDisplayComponent', () => {
  let component: EcheqDisplayComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EcheqDisplayComponent>;
  const metaData: MetaData = new MetaData();
  // const metaDataInfo = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;


  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: new MockActivatedRoute().withData({submission:{ answers:{} } }) }
      ],
      imports:[
        ParticipantEcheqModule
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EcheqDisplayComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  fit('should create component', () => {
    component.echeq = {
      definition: {
        title: 'test title',
        awardedVPoints: 0,
        numPages: 9
      }
   }
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

But then I get this error:
```

```
Property 'answers' is missing in type '{ definition: { title: string; awardedVPoints: number; numPages: number; }; }' but required in type 'EcheqSubmissionApi'.ts(2741)
echeqSubmissionApi.ts(59, 5): 'answers' is declared here.
```

I have it now like this:

```
fit('should create component', () => {
    component.echeq = {
      definition: {
        title: 'test title',
        awardedVPoints: 0,
        numPages:9
      }
    } as EcheqSubmissionApi;
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

```
export interface EcheqSubmissionApi { 
    /**
     * Primary key of this submission (server set).
     */
    id?: string;
    definition?: EcheqDefinitionApi;
    /**
     * Id of the prof who assigned this eCheq (server set).
     */
    assignedByProfId?: string;
    /**
     * Name of the prof who assigned this eCheq (server set). Only set on get operations. May be null if assigned by the system.
     */
    assignedByProfName?: string;
    /**
     * Id of the organisation who assigned this eCheq (server set).
     */
    assignedByOrgId?: number;
    /**
     * Participant ID of the patient this eCheq is assigned to (server set).
     */
    assignedToId?: string;
    /**
     * When this submission was assigned (UTC, server set).
     */
    assignedOnUtc?: Date;
    /**
     * If set until when the eCheq can be submitted.
     */
    validUntilUtc?: Date;
    /**
     * Whether the eCheq has been started and whether it has been submitted (server set).
     */
    status?: EcheqSubmissionApi.StatusEnum;
    /**
     * When this submission was completed (UTC, server set).
     */
    submittedOnUtc?: Date;
    /**
     * Answers of form.  In the form of a json object with name and value of the questions  {      \"nameOfQuestion\" : \"valueOfQuestion\"  }
     */
    answers: object;
    /**
     * initialValues of form.  In the form of a json object with name and value of variables  {      \"nameOfQuestion\" : \"valueOfQuestion\"  }
     */
    initialValues?: object;
    /**
     * The page the participant is currently on
     */
    currentPage?: number;
    /**
     * The progress of the echeq in percentage
     */
    progress?: number;
}
export namespace EcheqSubmissionApi {
    export type StatusEnum = 'New' | 'Active' | 'Submitted';
    export const StatusEnum = {
        New: 'New' as StatusEnum,
        Active: 'Active' as StatusEnum,
        Submitted: 'Submitted' as StatusEnum
    };
}
```

But if I run the unit test, I still get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'numPages' of undefined
```

Comment: How is the metaData in the test related to the component? Where does the error come from? Where is the input? Give a [mcve].

Comment: It's unclear how you think those pieces are related. I'd recommend reading and understanding e.g. https://angular.io/guide/testing.

Comment: Could you show us the MockActivatedRoute file that you are importing in your test? You are trying to set the numpages in the metadata object you are creating, but that won't affect the component. The content of the mockActivatedRoute injected through is where the data will come from

Comment: `definition: { title: 'test title', awardedVPoints: 0, numPages: 9 } as EcheqSubmissionApi`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

```js
component.metadata = /// whatever you want this to be
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your error with  `numPages: echeq.definition.numPages`. Endeed, `echeq` is also undefined.

You can try :

```
component.echeq = {
   definition: {
     numPages: 9
   }
}
```

Or better way would be to returns this value from `this.route.snapshot.data['submission'];` so from `MockActivatedRoute`

**UPDATE**:

And update `MockActivatedRoute` to allows dynamic parameters:

```
export class MockActivatedRoute {
  snapshot = {
      data: {}
  };

  constructor(){}

  withData(data:any): MockActivatedRoute {
     this.snapchot.data = data;
     return this;
 }
}
```

So now in your test, you can use it :

```
{ provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: new MockActivatedRoute().withData({submission:{ answers:{} } }) }
```

Comment: I have improved my answer

Comment: I have no time left for this problem. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

No problem. It was an easy:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
      ],
      imports:[
        ParticipantEcheqModule,
        RouterTestingModule
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```